# What does suspended, with wait time of 450 seconds on CXPACKET indicate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, wait-types

I am monitoring the requests and sessions using dmv's.

I am seeing a session that is having suspended status, which means it is waiting for something like IO. Yet the wait time is showing as 450000 ms on CXPACKET.

What does this indicate? Does it mean that it has been 450000ms so far that the result of parallel processing is being combined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that it has been 450000ms so far that the result of parallel processing is being combined?

It simply means that a parallel operation has been running for at least 450sec.  Some other thread in the same session is in a non-CXPACKET wait or is actively running.